# Merging two sorted arrays using two pointers method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a leetcode question.
The question is to merge two sorted arrays :

**Input:**
arr1 = [2,4,7,9 ]
arr2 = [1,3,5,11,13]

**Output**
[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13]

My solution looks something like :

```js
function mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr1, arr2){
    let newArr = [];
    let newArrSize = (arr1.length + arr2.length) - 1;
    let i = arr1.length - 1;
    let j = arr2.length - 1;

    while(i >= 0 || j>=0){
        if(arr1[i] > arr2[j]){
            newArr[newArrSize] = arr1[i];
            newArrSize--;
            i--;
        }
        if(arr2[j] > arr1[i]){
            newArr[newArrSize] = arr2[j];
            newArrSize--;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
    let arr1 = [2,4,7,9 ]
    let arr2 = [1,3,5,11,13];
    console.log(mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr1,arr2));
```

The problem here is that it goes into an infinite loop and exits. I think the while codition am using is wrong but what's wrong ?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `const out = [...arr1, ...arr2].sort();`

Comment: Once one of `i` or `j` becomes negative the `arr1[i] > arr2[j]` tests will always fail because one of the values will be undefined, so the other counter will never reach 0

Comment: @Evert Its an algorithm question so i need to write a solution for that

Comment: @Mishonda in that case I can _really_ recommend you start using a step-through debugger! It will likely become very obvious where the flaw is

Answer (score 0):

You could just use concat and sort, but if you're supposed to implement it yourself:

```
function mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr1, arr2){
    let newArr = [];
    let i = arr1.length;
    let j = arr2.length;
    let newArrSize = i + j;

    while(newArrSize > 0){
        if(typeof arr2[j-1] == 'undefined' || (arr1[i-1] > arr2[j-1])){
            console.log('-', i, arr1[i-1])
            newArr[newArrSize-1] = arr1[i-1];
            newArrSize--;
            i--;
        }else if(typeof arr1[i-1] == 'undefined' || (arr2[j-1] > arr1[i-1])){
            console.log('j', j, arr2[j-1])
            newArr[newArrSize-1] = arr2[j-1];
            newArrSize--;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a little explanation how it works and why these checks ?

Comment: In your while loop what you are checking is wrong. You should use AND operator (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`). that's why the condition in the while loop will never be `false`. I changed that to newArrSize because it makes more sense in terms of algorithms. For the IF statements, you need to check whether the index you are trying to compare exists in the first place (by checking if its type is undefined), to prevent comparing undefined with some value.

Comment: Yeah exactly why are we using AND instead of OR ??

Comment: Yes, sorry, OR was correct. That was a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question -and without providing you a solution- the problem with your loop is that `i` will always be higher than `0`, the same as `j`. And thus, it enters an infinite loop. Why? Because you only rest to either of them about half the times the length of the array. Your array could be of length 8, and only on 3 occasions hit the `if`.

How do you think you can stop it?

Answer (score -1):

Use `...` spread operator to merge and `sort()` funtion to sort arrays

```
var merged = [...arr1, ...arr2]
merged.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
console.log(merged)
```

Comment: It's a leetcode question!